# iphone development: sending app requests to multiple facebook friends from friendpicker

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been searching so long bu could not find any suitable answer so if you have any idea it would be perfect.

In my app i have friendpicker controller it lists all my friends. When I select some of them and press done button I can successfully log the ones I selected. so there is no problem. But what i want to do is sending app request to the selected users. How can I do that? what I need is sending multiple app requests to the friends which are selected from the friendpicker. Thank you

(Facebook SDK 3.5)

Comment: But in new privacy policy you can't post on your friend's wall by FB. Only you can tag your friends

Comment: You may read this resource:

1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508229/all-users-in-param-ids-must-have-accepted-tos-error
2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/requests/
3. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/requests/
4. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
5. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919218/sending-app-requests-to-multiple-recipients-using-graph-api

Comment: @AshutoshMishra I dont want to post to their walls. I just want to send app request. It will be seen on their requests tab at the app center

Comment: I have exactly the same question. Did you get it?

Answer (score -1):

```
You should design experiences into your app to allow users to send requests to     friend to drive re-engagement. Some design experiences include giving users the ability to request gifts, accept gifts, or help them complete a mission in your app. For example in Diamond Dash you can send a life to a friend. If that friend has not been using the app for a while this could help re-engage them.

Another design experience to consider is to allow users invite their friends to use    your app. For example, there are apps that ask users to rate the app after some time. If you wanted to build something similar to drive engagement you could ask users to invite their friends. Wherever you have a button or call to action to rate   the app, think about adding a flow to invite friends.

These user-generated requests are initiated when the app enables the user to select one or more friends to send a request to.

We will walk you through the steps to send out an invite or a request:

Triggering when the invitation or request is sent
Sending the request
Sending additional data with the request, such as a virtual gift
```

See this tutorial: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/

This may help you.